# Erro: "Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo"void" em "EventHandler"

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, button

Estava tentando fazer um botão que passava as informações de uma entry e de um StackLayout e esse erro me aparece:

```
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        Entry entry = new Entry() { Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric };

        Button button = new Button();

        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                button,
                entry
            }
        };

        button.Clicked += Button_Clicked(stack, entry); //O erro aparece nessa linha
    }
    private async void Button_Clicked(StackLayout stack, Entry entry)
    {
        int qtd_in = Int16.Parse(entry.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < qtd_in; i++)
        {
            Entry entradas = new Entry();
            stack.Children.Add(entradas);
        }//O código deveria criar novas entradas de acordo com a primeira entry
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A descrição do seu erro ja diz tudo, o clicked espera um event handler de retorno e o seu método é do tipo void, a forma correta de se chamar o seu método seria mais ou menos assim:

```
button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
 Button_Clicked(stack, entry);
}
```